# Share a VPN connection over WiFi

Tags: ubuntu, networking, networkmanager, vpn, connection-sharing

I've got two computers connected to the same router `10.9.8.1`:

- Computer A `10.9.8.2` runs Windows 10 Insider Preview. Insider Preview has VPN broken and can't be rolled back. :(
- Computer B `10.9.8.3` runs Linux Mint and has a VPN connection set up via `openconnect`.

Here's what `ipconfig` reports on B (fragment):

```
tun0      Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
          inet addr:10.23.8.183  P-t-P:10.23.8.183  Mask:255.255.255.255
          inet6 addr: fe80::7fb2:5598:b02e:e541/64 Scope:Link
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1410  Metric:1
          RX packets:24 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:42 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:500 
          RX bytes:7005 (7.0 KB)  TX bytes:3243 (3.2 KB)

wlp3s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 60:67:20:36:6f:a4  
          inet addr:10.9.8.3  Bcast:10.9.8.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::8e96:7526:ff54:d1be/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:22511502 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:16052631 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:24451442281 (24.4 GB)  TX bytes:6038264731 (6.0 GB)
```

I need to access resources behind VPN from computer A.

I'm thinking of configuring routes on A in such a way so that it would access VPN resources through B while using the router directly for everything else.

In the worst case, I can connect the two computers directly, but I would like to avoid that if possible.

On Windows, I can simply mark any adapter as shared. But when I do the same thing on Linux, the adapter loses connectivity. Not sure how to do that correctly.

Comment: Set routes for the remote nets (behind B) on A (as you already mentioned). You need to enable forwarding on wlp3s0 via sysctl and maybe iptables/firewall. Additionally you may need to NAT outgoing connections on tun0 onto 10.23.8.183. If you get stuck, please update your question.

Comment: I'm not familiar with `iptables`. I tried to follow this guide very carefully: http://www.techytalk.info/internet-connection-sharing-without-network-manager-on-ubuntu-linux/ But no luck. :( From computer A, I do a traceroute and see that it hits computer B for resources-behind-VPN, but can't ping them. :(

Comment: @xx4h Maybe if you expanded your comment to a full-fledged answer with enough detail, I'd be able to set it up, or at least tell exactly what's wrong. "Maybe some iptables" is not detailed enough for me. :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Routing

On host `A` you need to route all traffic for the destination network to host `B`. I will assume this is something like `192.168.0.0/24`

for linux (on host `A`):

```
ip r a 192.168.0.0/24 via 10.9.8.3 dev eth0
```

for windows (on host `A`):

```
route ADD 192.168.0.0 MASK 255.255.255.0 10.9.8.3
```

---

### Forwarding

After routing is in place, all packages for the network `192.168.0.0/24` will be send to host `B`.

To allow packages to be forwarded from `wlp3s0` to `tun0` on host `B`, you need to enable IP forwarding.

To temporary enable IP forwarding for all interfaces:

```
sysctl net.ipv4.conf.all.forwarding=1
```

To enable this change permanently, add new line to `/etc/sysctl.conf`:

```
net.ipv4.conf.all.forwarding = 1
```

Additionally to interface settings, `iptables` could be active and need to allow package forwarding.

To check if `iptables` is active (at least for the `FORWARD` chain):

```
iptables -L FORWARD -nv
```

If the chain has no rules and the policy says `ACCEPT`, you are good to go, if not, you need to add relevant rules to allow forwarding for `192.168.0.0/24`.

Allow forwarding all packages to `192.168.0.0/24` on `wlp3s0`:

```
iptables -I FORWARD -i wlp3s0 -d 192.168.0.0/24 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

the `RELATED,ESTABLISHED` automatically allows the return packages.

---

### NAT

Now, after forwarding is set up, packages will be send into the tunnel. But as far as the remote network behind the VPN does not know our local network, which is normally the case, we need to `NAT` all packages which come from our local network and will go into the VPN to the address, we got from the VPN-Server (which is the IP on the `tun0`).

To do this, you need to create a `MASQUERADE` rule in the `POSTROUTING` table:

```
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -o tun0 -j MASQUERADE
```

This will nat all outgoing packages on `tun0` to the interface`s IP.

Comment: It works! THANK YOU! *tears of joy* Likely, it's the `FORWARD` part that I was missing. PS Are you sure the `sysctl` directive is not `net.ipv4.ip_forward`? That's what other guides are saying. I used both.

Comment: Enabling `net.ipv4.conf.all.forwarding` will enable `net.ipv4.ip_forward` too.

Comment: I seem to lose some of this configuration on every reboot. Can you please update the answer with a recommended way to make the configuration persistent?

Comment: The iptables rules will pass packets in `wlp3s0` interface that are destined to `192.168.0.0/24`.  But how they will be passed to `tun0` interface? Dont you need a separate routing table entry for this?

Comment: Most of the time vpn servers push routes to the clients on connect connect. So, if the connection is successfully established from the client to the vpn server, the routes for the remote networks are in place.